# Nodejs redirection is not working

Tags: jquery, node.js, forms, express, url-routing

I am new to node . Whatever I am trying to is a simple from submission and after submission redirect to specific template . Here is my directory structure

- node_modules
- index.js
- login.html
- test.html

Here is my `index.js` file

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');

});

app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body.user);
    console.log(request.body.password);
    if (request.body.user === "test@gmail.com" && request.body.password === "123") {
        console.log("logged in");
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.setHeader("Location", "/home");
        response.end();
    }
});

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');

});

http.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

In my `login.html` file I have a simple form

```
        <label for="user" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="user" class="form-control" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus autocomplete="on">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="user[password]" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" id="submit">Sign in</button>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var user, pass;
            $("#submit").click(function(event) {
                user = $("#user").val();
                pass = $("#password").val();
                $.post("/login", {user: user, password: pass}, function(data) {
                    if (data === 'done')
                    {
                        alert("login success");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I run my app at `localhost:3001` `login.html` appears , if I submit the form with `username:test@gamil.com` and `password:123` it doesn't redirect to `test.html` , though  I can read the console message `"logged in"` .

Comment: Try `response.redirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the request to `/login` through an AJAX call (`$.post()`), just let the form submit to it instead:

```
<form action='/login' method='post'>
...
</form>
```

In your current situation, you're redirecting the *AJAX request* to `/home`, not your entire page.

Also, your handler does nothing when the username and/or password don't match, which means that the request will stall. You need to send a response back in that case as well (perhaps redirect to an error page, or to the login page again).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body.user);
    console.log(request.body.password);
    if (request.body.user === "test@gmail.com" && request.body.password === "123") {
        console.log("logged in");
        response.redirect('/home')
    }
});
```

Documentation on express redirect here(http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)

Comment: thanks , now it is not showing any error , even if I debug  it , it clearly says

"200 get home" , but it simply doesn't open my test.html file